# Use OpenSSH to make a key exchange with NTRU Prime

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys

I would like to make a key exchange for a symmetric key from the client to the server with the NTRU Prime algorithm (for test reasons). I already installed OpenSSH 9.1 on both sides and checked already if everything is working (connection, key exchange part of it etc.). It is. However, I am not sure how I do exactly key exchange. I did not find much on the internet or the man pages. I only found this command:

```
ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+"sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com" user@server
```

which, If I understood it right, uses a specific algorithm for key exchange. However, after using it I got only an SSH connection but wasn't able to do any key exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple terms, SSH first uses a key exchange algorithm to securely exchange a symmetric key, which is used in encrypting the connection.

Add the option "-v" to your command and you'll see all the gory details of establishing a ssh connection.
Look for a line containing "kex: algorithm:" showing you the actual key exchange algorithm used.